# CEFSharp "Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined\n@ about:blank:1:0"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, wpf, cefsharp

I am using CEFSharp in WPF app.

Currently i am loading local html file in chromium based browser.

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="buttonTest" Content="Click me" Grid.Row="0" Width="50px" Height="30px" Click="buttonTest_Click" />
    <!--<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Grid.Row="1" />-->
    <!--<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Grid.Row="1" />-->
    <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

cs

```
BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
browserSettings.Javascript = CefState.Enabled;
browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
webBrowser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;    
webBrowser.Address = "file:///" + path;
```

Loading html is working completely fine.

Now i am trying to call javascript function on a click of WPF Button.

```
private async void buttonTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (webBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            var task = await webBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.body.style.background = 'red';");
            var task1 = await webBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("startInterval()", new Object { });
            //webBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert(2 + 2);");
        }

        //webBrowser.InvokeScript("startInterval");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
     }
}
```

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            'use strict';

            function startInterval() {
                alert("qqf5");
            }

            function clearInterval() {

            }

            $("#buttonGetData").click(function () {
                startInterval();
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <button type="button" id="buttonGetData">Get Data!</button>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

From wpf if i click on button then page background color is changed but method is not called.

But if i click on from html page then it it working fine.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: @amaitland i have read that i can execute javscript but i am not able to call java script function or method.So i think rendering is done. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @amaitland Just FYI i am able to call javascript to .net method. but not javascript function from .net.

Comment: Have you loaded your HTML page, checked with `wb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync()`? Do you have also the issue, if you put the function definition to the `<body>`?

Comment: Reviewing closer and the problem is with your JavaScript. startInterval is not accessible as it only exists within the context of your anonymous function.

Comment: @amaitland Correct issues is with javascript. I can't use methods inside jquery function. So if i write as normal javascript function then its working fine.